# How to Loop program that counts, digits and Letters?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop

This program is suppose to count the number of digits, words ( i.e Abc, fish...) upper case letters, and longest word length inputted.
I am having trouble properly writing the code to identify word count and number of letters inputted. When I run it only the number of digits seen seems to work and I do not know how to make the program count the longest word inputted.Am I on the right track? Any help is greatly appreciated!

My code:

```
    '#include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    int main(){ 
        char s = '0';
        char sentinel = '.';
        int countWords = 0;
        int countDigits = 0;
        int countLetters = 0;
        int countUppers = 0;
        cout << "Enter your string: " << endl;
        while (cin >> s){
            if (isdigit(s)){
                countDigits++;
            }
            else if (isupper(s)){
                countUppers++;
                }
            else if (isspace(s)){
                countWords++;
            }

            cout << "# of Digits: " << countDigits << endl;
            cout << "# of Uppers: " << countUppers << endl;
            cout << "# of Words: " << countWords << endl;
            cout << "Longest word length" << countLetters << endl;
        }

        system("PAUSE");
    }
    /*getline(cin, s);
    const int size = s.length();
    cout << "The total number of characters entered is: " << size << endl;*/'
```

Comment: Perhaps we should back up a little. Do you know what char s = '0'; cin >> s; does?

Comment: Doesnt cin >> s refer to inputting characters into the loop? And char s = '0' initializes it?

Comment: not characters, it stores 1 single character every iteration. Now you said 'count the number of digits, words ( i.e Abc, fish...) upper case letters, and longest word length inputted'. Do you see the problem?

Comment: No sorry I don't. Can you explain? I thought my program was attempting to do that.

Comment: A word can contain more than 1 character, you are not storing the characters anywhere to build up a word. If you mean characters why did you type: words ( i.e Abc, fish...)? Even if you write "fish" in the input, you will only get 1 character every iteration, so the only word you can capture in english is probably "a" and the longest word letter is also going to be 1. Do you see the problem now? use std::string instead of char or at least an array of chars

Comment: Ohhhh OK I see the problem. My intentions were to use char as it could be easily used with "isdigit" and such to be able to count how many digits were inputted. Is there a way I would be able to still apply that?

Comment: Yes it is :), you can loop through the string check each character with std::isdigit(c) and if every char is a digit you cast it to int.  std::string str = "25";
 int x = std::stoi(str);. Also if you want to find the longest word you should perhaps save all the inputs into a vector<std::string> and than iterate through all of them to find whatever you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, this is an example of how you can solve the problem. Hope you find it useful.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>

bool IsNumber(const std::string _str)
{
    return !_str.empty() && std::find_if(_str.begin(),_str.end(), [](char c) { return !std::isdigit(c); }) == _str.end();
}

bool IsUpper(const std::string _str)
{
    return !_str.empty() && std::find_if(std::begin(_str), std::end(_str), [](char c) { return !(std::isupper(c)); }) == _str.end();
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> listInputs;
    std::string input;
    const int numberOfInputs = 5;

    std::cout << "Input 5 different stuff. Words, Uppercase words, digits..." << std::endl << std::endl;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < numberOfInputs; ++i)
    {
        //ask the question
        std::cout << "Input " << i+1 << ": " << std::flush;
        std::cin >> input;
        std::cout << std::endl;
        listInputs.push_back(input);
    }

    //check some shit
    int countWords = 0;
    int countDigits = 0;
    int countLetters = 0;
    int countUppers = 0;
    int longestWordSize = 0;

    for (const auto& i : listInputs)
    {
        //check if its a digit
        if (IsNumber(i))
        {
            ++countDigits;
        }
        else
        {
            longestWordSize = (i.length() > longestWordSize) ? i.length() : longestWordSize;
            ++countWords;
            countLetters += i.length();
            if (IsUpper(i))
            {
                ++countUppers;
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << std::endl << "######## THE RESULT BABY ########" << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Number of words found: " << countWords << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Number of Digits found: " << countDigits << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Number of uppercase words found: " << countUppers << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The longest word length was: " << longestWordSize << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```